# Egress Istio rule won't work

Tags: kubernetes, istio

I have a deployment istio is injected in with access to the google maps distance matrix api. If I run the istioctl kube-inject with `--includeIPRanges 10.0.0.0/8` it seems to work. If I remove this flag and instead apply a egress rule it won't work:

`apiVersion: config.istio.io/v1alpha2
kind: EgressRule
metadata:
  name: google-egress-rule
  namespace: microservices
spec:
  destination:
    service: "maps.googleapis.com"
  ports:
    - port: 443
      protocol: https
    - port: 80
      protocol: http`

Both, deployment and Egress rule are in the same namespace (microservices).

Any idea where my fault is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I see by running `curl maps.googleapis.com`, it redirects to https://developers.google.com/maps/.

Two issues here:

1. You have specify an additional EgressRule for `developers.google.com`
2. Currently you have to access https external sites by issuing http requests to port 443, like `curl http://developers.google.com/maps:443`. Istio proxy will open an https connection to `developers.google.com` for you. Unfortunately, currently there is no other way to do it, except for using `--includeIPRanges`.

Comment: Thank you Vadim, the maps.googleapis.com at this point don't do a redirect, this is only for the root domain (was also my first suppose). As you already told in issue 2 I have to use http with 443 as port value. The problem was here that the Java SDK has a fixed URL in it... but with some reflection magic ;-) it was possible.
Thank you for your answer :-)

Comment: Glad to hear it helped :)